# SIunitx error when using lighter weight

Tags: fonts, siunitx

Using the SIunitx package with montserrat package doesn't produce the desired result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[defaultfam,light,scale=0.85]{montserrat}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{%
 mode = math, % Same error if mode = text is used
% detect-all, % When, uncommented, the error described below occurs
% detect-weight,  % When, uncommented, the error described below occurs
}  

\begin{document}
This is the weight and family of text desired but when siunitx shows heavier weight: \SI{75}{\micro\metre}
\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image: Image showing incorrect font weight for units and number.]

When options `detect-weight` or `detect-all` are used, the following error is produced:

```
[no file]:18: Undefined control sequence. [...hows heavier weight: \SI{75}{\micro\metre}]
[no file]:18: Undefined control sequence. [...hows heavier weight: \SI{75}{\micro\metre}]
```

The PDF, notwithstanding the compilation error, the PDF shows the desired result:

[image: Desired results]

The log file indicates:

```
Package: siunitx 2018-05-11 v2.7q A comprehensive (SI) units package
```

and reports the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\__siunitx_font_weight: ->\lseries 

l.18 ...hows heavier weight: \SI{75}{\micro\metre}
```

Comment: Do you need `mode = math`? With `mode = text` it works without errors.

Comment: @RalfStubner If you uncomment `detect-weight` and set `math = text` in the MWE, the same error occurs. I have updated the MWE to indicate this.

Comment: Indeed. But there is no error and the right fonts if you only use `mode = text` without any of the `detect-*` options.

Comment: @RalfStubner your suggestion works.

Comment: @RalfStubner - There may be valid reasons (which the OP hasn't pointed out so far) for setting `mode=math`. (See, e.g., p. 77 of the user guide of the `siunitx` package.) The work-around for this contingency is set set `detect-mode` (but certainly not `detect-all`) when loading `siunitx`.

Comment: @Mico Agreed. That's why I asked whether the OP needs `mode = math`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provide a definition for the missing command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[defaultfam,light,scale=0.85]{montserrat}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{%
 mode = math, % Same error if mode = text is used
 detect-all, % When, uncommented, the error described below occurs
 %detect-weight,  % When, uncommented, the error described below occurs
}

\DeclareRobustCommand\lseries{\fontseries{l}\selectfont}

\begin{document}
This is the weight and family of text desired but when siunitx shows heavier weight: \SI{75}{\micro\metre}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to load `siunitx` with the option `detect-mode`. (Please see the bottom of p. 17 and the top of p. 18 of the user guide of the `siunitx` package for the differences between `detect-mode`, `detect-weight`, etc.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry} % optional
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[defaultfam,light,scale=0.85]{montserrat}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{ mode = math , detect-mode }  

\begin{document}
This is the weight and family of text desired. siunitx now shows the correct, i.e, thin weight: \SI{75}{\micro\metre}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `mode = text` without any any `detect-*` options  giving you the same output even when the unit is used in math mode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[defaultfam,light,scale=0.85]{montserrat}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{ mode = text }

\begin{document}
This is the weight and family of text desired but when siunitx shows
heavier weight: \SI{75}{\micro\metre} $\SI{75}{\micro\metre}$
\end{document}
```

[image]